# Can't fetch POST request from node.js when server is hosted in specific path

Tags: node.js, http, server

I have a website built with wordpress and one of it's routes serves a node.js server.
Let's suppose `https://www.wordpress.com/` is the domain and the `node.js` route is `https://www.wordpress.com/node`.

[Hosting service settings (sorry they aren't in english)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBcr0.jpg)

The node server is running a `reactjs` frontend and this frontend makes requests to the server through the fetch api. The request URLs looks like this `https://www.wordpress.com/node/api/user-login`. In my react code I have this to create the request

```
res = await fetch("api/user-login/", {
  headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  method: "POST",
  body,
})
```

I expected the server to POST, but instead I got this error message

```
404 Not Found
Cannot POST //api/user-login/
```

*I don't know why the two slashes too*
[Request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LncOr.png) *please note that the links painted in blue are equivalent to the wordpress.com/node example*

My routes.js and my server.js files (on the backend side) look like this

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))
app.use("/api", require("./src/routes"))
app.get('/', function(_req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
})
```

**src/routes.js**

```
const routes = express.Router()

routes.post("/user-login", login)
routes.get("/refresh-token", refreshToken)

module.exports = routes
```

I don't know why I can't post to this route. They are in the same site, so *I think* CORS is not a problem.

Another important point is that the wordpress website is using the **https** protocol and I tried to solve the `Cannot POST` error setting the node server with and without https, but neither worked (I used the same certificate and key of the wordpress).

Any answer here are appreciated, thank you so much and I'm sorry for my bad English, once again thank you.

Comment: Try post using something like Postman

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I tried using Postman and Insomnia. Neither worked, I also got this Cannot POST error

Comment: Which HTTP error code?

Comment: Error 404 not found

Comment: Can you view us the code of the `login` method?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZgdNUD5M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line in **server.js** and it worked, maybe it's a problem from the calling in the API, I don't know exactly why it was trying to POST to "`//api`" (with two slashes).

```
app.use("//api", require("./src/routes"))
```

Anyway, thank you all for helping